# Do production boosts affect resource acquisition during offline progression?

Tags: kittens-game

I'm playing the app version of Kittens Game. Consequently the game runs most of the time in offline mode (due to the smartphone display being off).

I'm wondering if the various production boosts still affect resource production although being offline.

Since magnetos became available I've noticed a strange behavior. Magnetos consume oil and with magnetos turned on my oil consumption is higher than my total oil production. So I'm loosing oil (currently at -1/sec), yet my oil never gets to zero. Whenever I close the app / turn the display off and turn it on again after a while, the amount of oil has increased instead of decreased.

Therefore I assume that at least magnetos don't affect resource acquisition during offline mode (otherwise they would consume oil). Since the app version runs 99% in offline mode it looks like magnetos are completely useless. They cost a lot of resources but don't affect the game most of the time in the app version. Is this true?

I'm also wondering if this is true for various other production boosts like happiness, faith, paragon points and so on.

Meanwhile I've also asked this question at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kgmobile/comments/7apm00/production_boosts_during_offline_progression/) since I didn't got an answer so far.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I've noticed the same thing in my app version as well (iPhone). I had a negative value for my Uranium production and somehow woke up to it being at capacity, yet the production value remained negative. I assume that the mechanic that is affecting my uranium and your oil is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the answers from user Origonn to [my cross-post at reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kgmobile/comments/7apm00/production_boosts_during_offline_progression/):

> Negative production isn't being calculated / used during offline play.
>
> It's part of the 1.2.7b changelog to 'fix' this 'feature'
>
> https://www.reddit.com/r/kgmobile/comments/728e76/kg_mobile_127b_android/

And from user DecidedSloth:

> Actually I'm pretty sure the resource generation rate when offline is
>   just half, which realistically does the same thing as megnetos being
>   100% instead of 300%. I think bloodrizer confirmed that this was
>   intended.

So it looks like resources don't get consumed during offline play. Similarly, production boost are reduced.